# Pegar ultimo valor de tabela do banco e mostrar no JTextField

Tags: java, sql-server

Tenho um programa aqui na fábrica que, a cada 1 minuto, um equipamento ligado a um supervisório lança um valor direto em uma tabela no banco de dados (SQL Server).

Gostaria de saber como faço para pegar sempre o último valor e mostrar em um `JTextField`, e a cada minuto ele tentar fazer essa consulta.

No caso, esse código me atende perfeitamente, mas a minha dúvida agora como faço para pegar o último valor do banco de dados que no caso seria (SQL Server).

```
    int delay = 5000;   // delay de 5 seg.
    int interval = 5000;  // intervalo de 1 seg.
    Timer timer = new Timer();

    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
        public void run() {
          jTextField6.setText("1");
        }
    }, delay, interval);
}
```

Comment: Sim, é possivel. O que você já fez?

Comment: @Articuno, Até o momento fiz apenas a alteração desses valores, para que a pessoa possa setar os valores de um equipamento de dentro do escritorio, mas para que isso fique leal, eu precisava trazer esse valor real pq o equipamento mesmo setando, ele nunca chega na temperatura ideal, pois ele sempre tem a variação.

Comment: No caso de java-swing, existe a classe [`swing.Timer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html) que provavelmente será a que você precisará usar. [**Neste link**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) ensina como ela funciona e como usar, se você apresentar algo que já fez no formato de um **[mcve]**, posso demonstrar seu uso na prática.

Comment: No momento não tenho muito que te apresentar, é mais uma duvida e de que maneira posso começar.

Comment: Pois é, o problema é que a duvida se torna ampla da forma como está a pergunta, pois além dessa maneira que expliquei, existem inumeras outras que não cabe explicar todas aqui. Se você apresentar algo para exemplificar o que pretente em um **[mcve]**, fica mais facil sugerir algo mais especifico.

Comment: Blz, vou ver oq da pra fazer com o Timer, e caso tenha duvida recorro a vocês.

Comment: Não é essa a classe timer que você deveria usar. É a que deixei o link, pois se trata de interface gráfica.

Comment: Mas nesse caso se eu colocar uma tarefa para ele ir no banco e buscar a ultima informação daria certo também, não? ou poderia dar problemas futuros?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se for utilizar a classe `java.util.Timer`, certifique-se de que o componente seja atualizado dentro da [**EDT**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tags/event-dispatch-thread/info), pois essa Thread é que deve ser a única responsável por gerenciar componentes da API swing:

```
int delay = 5000;   // delay de 5 seg.
int interval = 5000;  // intervalo de 1 seg.
Timer timer = new Timer();

timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
    public void run() {
      SwingUtilities.InvokeLater(()-> jTextField6.setText("1"));
    }
}, delay, interval);
```

Lembrando que o tempo seja 1 minuto, o intervalo precisa ser 60*1000 pois o argumento que o método [`scheduleFixedRate()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html#scheduleAtFixedRate-java.util.TimerTask-long-long-) espera tanto o *delay* (atraso pra primeira execução) quanto o *interval*(tempo entre as repetições) em milissegundos.

Quanto a busca na tabela, pelo que entendi você quer buscar o último resultado inserido na tabela, provavelmente precisará adaptar a *query* abaixo dentro do `TimerTask`, retornando o campo somente da última linha da tabela:

```sql
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM <tabela> ORDER BY <campo a ser ordenado> DESC
```

Comment: Estou tentando mostrar m um optionpane, mas não está funcionando. da uma olhadinha ai q vou postar la em cima

Comment: @Lucas16 sem um [mcve] este é o maximo que posso ajudar, pois não tem como eu simular algo que não foi apresentado. a resposta mesmo foi feita baseada no que supostamente eu entendi do problema. E a edição inseriu uma duvida completamente diferente da original por isso, reverti a pergunta.

Comment: Entendi. Fico grato, deu certo em questão do tempo, mas meu problema agora está na hora de buscar as informações, mas vc já me ajudou muito. obrigado.