# Pegar ultima informação sql server pelo netbeans jdbc

Tags: java, sql-server

Estou usando desta forma para tentar trazer a ultima informação registrada no sql server, mas por algum motivo desconhecido não está dando certo. Pesquisei em vários fórum e pelo visto é utilizado o mesmo método que estou usando:

```
        Class.forName(Auxiliar1.AcessoBanco.getDriver());
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(Auxiliar1.AcessoBanco.getUrl(), Auxiliar1.AcessoBanco.getUser(), Auxiliar1.AcessoBanco.getPass());
        String query1 = "Select MAX(ExtA_IndParafuso) FROM L11";

        Statement st = con.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(query1);
        jTextField6.setText(rs.toString());
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, rs.getInt(0));
```

Estou tentando trazer o resultado em forma de `Joptionpane` ou em formato de `Jtextfield` para teste.

Utilizei dessa maneira para tentar trazer os valores e mesmo assim sem sucesso.

```
int valor = rs.getInt(0);
jTextField6.setText(String.valueOf(valor));
```

Comment: Não é exatamente a mesma duvida que respondi? Pelo código parece que você não tentou conforme expliquei la.

Comment: Bom, lá fomos em uma pergunta e acabamos trazendo a questão do tempo, como estou com muita duvida nessa parte e pesquisei novamente e tenho certeza que outras pessoas também vão ter, achei válido trazer um tópico apenas para está duvida.

Comment: Eu lhe sugeri uma query la exclusiva para sql server que retorna a ultima linha.

Comment: Sim @Articuno, mas com ela não retornou nada, com essa pelo menso retorna algo.

Comment: Na verdade ele até retorna, mas retorna a mesma coisa. 'SQLServerResultSet:3' somando +1 a cada 5 sgundos.

Comment: tirei a questão do tempo e mesmo assim ele retorna da mesma forma, mas sem somar +1

Comment: Tentou fazer a buscar num SGBD ao inves de ser via programação? Se não, faça-o e compare os resultados

Comment: sim, o "Select MAx" me traz o valor. Será que não é por causa do st ou rs?

Comment: O erro é esse: `jTextField6.setText(rs.toString());`  percebe que ta transformando o resultset em string e não pegando o que ele retornou?

Comment: nesse caso como posso fazer? não consigo trazer ele float ou int

Comment: Depende do tipo desse campo. O jeito certo é recuperar pelos getters do resultset, onde geralmente é getXXXX, e esse XXX é o tipo do campo. Se não sabe qual usar, dá uma lida na [documentação do resultset](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html) e veja o tipo mais adequado pro campo que você ta pesquisando.

Comment: Ok, no meu caso preciso trazer valores do tipo float.

Comment: Se é float, porque ta usando getint? Você olhou no link que mandei?

Comment: Sim, mas eu tentei com int para ver se daria certo. Olhei sim, mas não entendi muto bem.

Answer (score 2):

Conforme já lhe disse na [outra pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/251218/28595), para retornar a ultima linha de uma tabela a query é essa:

```
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM <tabela> ORDER BY <campo a ser ordenado> DESC
```

A query que você está usando vai retornar o maior valor da coluna pesquisada, não necessariamente este será sempre a ultima, a não ser que essa coluna os valores sejam sempre adicionados em ordem crescente.

Conforme disse nos comentários, o valor retornado é float, então você utiliza o método `getFloat` do Resultset:

```
Class.forName(Auxiliar1.AcessoBanco.getDriver());
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(Auxiliar1.AcessoBanco.getUrl(), Auxiliar1.AcessoBanco.getUser(), Auxiliar1.AcessoBanco.getPass());
String query1 = "SELECT TOP 1 * FROM L11 ORDER BY ExtA_IndParafuso DESC";

Statement st = con.createStatement();
ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(query1);
jTextField6.setText(String.valueOf(rs.getFloat(<nome da coluna>)));
```

Comment: Articuno, tentei da sua maneira, mas não deu certo. 
Consegui fazer de uma forma q deu certo e acredito q vá ajudar bastante pessoas. Gostaria de postar a resposta para q as pessoas vejam a solução. como posso fazer?

Comment: @Lucas16 o que não deu certo? Se você não detalhar eu não consigo corrigi na resposta.

Comment: Começou dando esse erro "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: O conjunto de resultados não tem linha atual."

Comment: @Lucas16 Esse código não gera esse erro. Você precisa ser mais especifico.

Comment: Tentei de várias formas resolver seu código, mas ele não estava achando a coluna e nem a linha. depois deu erro para passar para float. para resolver esse problema eu fiz dessa maneira. vou postar e vc tira depois pra vc entender melhor

Comment: @Lucas16 edite a pergunta e mostre o schema de sua tabela e como estão alguns dados dela